# Is std::ratio calculation order in std::chrono::duration defined?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

If I reach the limits of the used integer (currently on my implementation `long long`) I either lose the first or the last digits, depending on what is first done (multiplication or division). Looking into my implementation multiplication is done first, so I'm losing the first digits. My question is, is it defined somewhere (best in the draft) what is done first?

### edit:

the implementation is like (shorted version):

```
count * num / den;
```

boost's implementation is the same.

Comment: Do you mean in any old arithmetic expression?  Like `long long a = b * c / d`?

Comment: @GuyGreer no, i mean `a = b * c / d` is different to `a = b / d * c`. the result is the same except the calculation prducces overflows.

Comment: There does not appear to be a specific definition for order of arithmetic operators on `std::ratio`. This means that the normal order applies, where multiplication and division have the same precedence and are evaluated left-to-right. In your example, multiplication is done before division. Anything else would have been really confusing.

Comment: @BartvanNierop do i understand it right? that means the implementation can change to `count / den * num`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**N3797**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) has this to say on `std::ratio`:

**N3797 [20.11.4] [ratio.arithmetic]**

> 2  If it is not possible to represent U or V with intmax_t, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, an implementation should yield correct values of U and V. If it is not possible to represent X or Y with intmax_t, the
>   program is ill-formed unless the implementation yields correct values of U and V.

It then gives the following:

```cpp
// The following cases may cause the program to be ill-formed under some implementations
static_assert(ratio_add<ratio<1,INT_MAX>, ratio<1,INT_MAX>>::num == 2,
"1/MAX+1/MAX == 2/MAX");
static_assert(ratio_add<ratio<1,INT_MAX>, ratio<1,INT_MAX>>::den == INT_MAX,
"1/MAX+1/MAX == 2/MAX");
static_assert(ratio_multiply<ratio<1,INT_MAX>, ratio<INT_MAX,2>>::num == 1,
"1/MAX * MAX/2 == 1/2");
static_assert(ratio_multiply<ratio<1,INT_MAX>, ratio<INT_MAX,2>>::den == 2,
"1/MAX * MAX/2 == 1/2");
```

This seems to me to suggest that if your program would overflow either the denominator or the numerator in intermediate calculations, the program is ill-formed.